# Join string within loop using awk (involve replacing an array with another)

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I'm writing a one-liner using `awk` to join strings within a loop.

Basically, there's an array of strings (I call it `a`), then I have another copy of that array (I call it `b` which is cloned using the `clone` function). I concatenate the string from array `a` (which is `m`) and `b` (which is `n`) together, then I store the concatenated string (`m n`) in a temporary array (`tmp`). Next, I replace array `b` with array `tmp`, and repeat the concatenation. This time, array `b` is array `tmp`, so the concatenated string would be `m n n`... and so on. I put the concatenation in a loop (here, it'll be repeated for three times) but I wasn't able to print the result out after the loop was done.

```
awk -v k=3 '
BEGIN {
        a["A"]
        a["T"]
        a["G"]
        a["C"]
        clone(a, b)
        for (i = 1; i < k; i++) {
                for (m in a) {
                        for (n in b) {
                                tmp[m n]
                        }
                }
                delete b
                clone(tmp, b)
        }
        for (i in b) {
                print i
        }
}


function clone(original, copy)
{
        for (i in original) {
                if (isarray(original[i])) {
                        copy[i][1] = ""
                        delete copy[i][1]
                        clone(original[i], copy[i])
                } else {
                        copy[i] = original[i]
                }
        }
}
'
```

I was also able to do this in Perl and Python. And below is how I did it.

Equivalent function in Perl:

```
sub kmer_generator {
    my ($k) = @_;
    my @bases_1 = ("A", "T", "G", "C");
    my @bases_2 = @bases_1;
    for (my $i = 1; $i < $k; $i++) {
        my @temporary;
        for my $base_1 (@bases_1) {
            for my $base_2 (@bases_2) {
                push @temporary, "$base_1" . "$base_2";
            };
        };
        undef @bases_2;
        @bases_2 = @temporary;
    };
    return @bases_2;
};
```

Equivalent function in Python:

```
def generate_kmer(k):
    bases_1 = ["A", "T", "G", "C"]
    bases_2 = bases_1.copy()
    i = 0
    while i < k - 1:
        i += 1
        temp = []
        for m in bases_1:
            for n in bases_2:
                temp.append(m + n)
        bases_2 = None
        bases_2 = temp
    return bases_2
```

Let's say the input is `k=2`. The output will be 16 combinations.

```
AA
AT
AG
AC
TA
TT
TG
TC
GA
GT
...
```

If the input is `k=3`, the output will be 64 combinations.

```
AAA
AAT
AAG
AAC
ATA
ATT
ATG
ATC
AGA
AGT
...
```

(I only show 10 examples)

Comment: `one-liner` Does it have to be one line? It's really simpler to write, maintain, read and understand nice looking code. Why not write eactly the same awk code?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a one-liner. I'm still trying to convert the same function in Perl and Python into `awk` code.

Comment: The awk script in your question was completely illegible so I formatted it for you by using `gawk -o-`. Please always format code in questions in a way that's easy for us to read like you did for your perl and python scripts. Also please [edit] your question to add concise, testable sample input and expected output that full demonstrate your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah, that was fun. The following script

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456316/209955
function clone(lhs, rhs) {
    for (i in rhs) {
        if (isarray(rhs[i])) {
            lhs[i][1] = ""
            delete lhs[i][1]
            clone(lhs[i], rhs[i])
        } else {
            lhs[i] = rhs[i]
        }
    }
}
# documentation...
# bases_2 is the return array
# k is an int
function generate_kmer(bases_2, k,
       # Local function variables, to preserve locality add them as arguments.
       bases_1, i, temp) {
    # Easy array initialization.
    split("A T G C", bases_1, " ")
    clone(bases_2, bases_1)
    # ugh?? I would do for (i = 1; i < k; i++) {
    i = 0
    while (i < k - 1) {
        i += 1
        temp = ""
        for (m in bases_1) {
            for (n in bases_2) {
                # I used just a string separated with spaces, easier to append.
                temp = temp (temp ? " " : "") bases_1[m] bases_2[n]
            }
        }
        split(temp, bases_2, " ")
    }
}
END {
    generate_kmer(output, 2)
    for (i in output) {
        printf("%s%s", output[i], i == length(output) ? "" : " ")
    }
    printf("\n")
}' </dev/null

python -c '
def generate_kmer(k):
    bases_1 = ["A", "T", "G", "C"]
    bases_2 = bases_1.copy()
    i = 0
    while i < k - 1:
        i += 1
        temp = []
        for m in bases_1:
            for n in bases_2:
                temp.append(m + n)
        bases_2 = temp
    return bases_2
print(" ".join(generate_kmer(2)))
'
```

outputs:

```
AA AT AG AC TA TT TG TC GA GT GG GC CA CT CG CC
AA AT AG AC TA TT TG TC GA GT GG GC CA CT CG CC
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil. It seems like there's no easy way to do it in `awk` tho. I tried to clear the array then replace it with a new one but it didn't work.

Comment: @Tiendu you got 1 answer immediately after asking your question, accepted it right away and declared there's no easy way to do it (whatever it is) in awk based on that 1 answer. You might be right but coming to that conclusion based on the 1 answer you got seems a but rushed.

Comment: @EdMorton Hi Ed, I'm still trying to make the method which replaces the array work. Any suggestions? Kamil's solution is to use split to replace the existing array and it's wonderful but I don't know why cloning doesn't work here.

Comment: @Tiendu aske a new question with a [mcve] that contains concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

if you're merely trying to batch generate all combinations of them, try something like this instead, (and without needing arrays or recursion at all) :

The only parameter needed to be specified is what's the character length (`"N"`) for each combination, and returning back a single string containing all `N`-length combos of the 4 base pairs, `ASCII` space separated.

It's reasonably fast because it performs `regex gsub()` instead of slow loops

```
 for __ in $(jot 14); do ( time ( nice echo "$__" | 

    mawk2 '
    function _____(____,_,__,___) { 
                  _="ATGC"
        ____ += ___="."
        gsub(___,"\\&&",_)
                 ___=" [^ ]+"
                     __=_
        gsub("[&]"," ",__)

        while(--____) { 
             gsub(___,_,__) 
        } 
        return __ 
    } 
    BEGIN { CONVFMT = "%.250g" } ($++NF = _____($!_))^_' 

    ) | pvE9 ) | 

    mawk 'BEGIN {  RS = "^$"
                 ORS = "\n\n" 
            } ($!NF = (__=NF) < (_+=_+=++_)^_ \
                     ? " | "(--__)" # combos | "($(_-=_)) \
                     : sprintf(" | %.f | \f\r\t%.*s..."  \
                               "\f\r\t\t\t\t... %.*s",
                      --__,___ = _--^_--*_-+—_, __ = $--_,
                       ___--, substr(__, length(__)-___) ) )'
done
```

> 

```
     out9: 11.0 B 0:00:00 [ 298KiB/s] [ 298KiB/s] [<=>                            ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 104% cpu 0.004 total
 | 4 # combos | 1  A T G C


     out9: 51.0 B 0:00:00 [1.25MiB/s] [1.25MiB/s] [<=>                            ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 103% cpu 0.004 total
 | 16 # combos | 2  AA AT AG AC TA TT TG TC GA GT GG GC CA CT CG CC


     out9:  259 B 0:00:00 [6.18MiB/s] [6.18MiB/s] [<=>                            ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 81% cpu 0.004 total
 | 64 # combos | 3  AAA AAT AAG AAC ATA ATT ATG ATC AGA AGT AGG AGC ACA ACT ACG ACC TAA TAT TAG TAC TTA TTT TTG TTC TGA TGT TGG TGC TCA TCT TCG TCC GAA GAT GAG GAC GTA GTT GTG GTC GGA GGT GGG GGC GCA GCT GCG GCC CAA CAT CAG CAC CTA CTT CTG CTC CGA CGT CGG CGC CCA CCT CCG CCC


     out9: 1.25KiB 0:00:00 [47.1MiB/s] [47.1MiB/s] [<=>                           ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 113% cpu 0.003 total
 | 256 | 
    4  AAAA AAAT AAAG AAAC AATA AATT AATG AATC AAGA AAGT AAGG AAGC AACA AACT AACG AACC ATAA ATAT ATAG ATAC ATTA ATTT ATTG ATTC ATGA...
                ... G CGTC CGGA CGGT CGGG CGGC CGCA CGCT CGCG CGCC CCAA CCAT CCAG CCAC CCTA CCTT CCTG CCTC CCGA CCGT CCGG CCGC CCCA CCCT CCCG CCCC


     out9: 6.00KiB 0:00:00 [ 195MiB/s] [ 195MiB/s] [<=>                           ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 115% cpu 0.003 total
 | 1024 | 
    5  AAAAA AAAAT AAAAG AAAAC AAATA AAATT AAATG AAATC AAAGA AAAGT AAAGG AAAGC AAACA AAACT AAACG AAACC AATAA AATAT AATAG AATAC AATT...
                ...  CCGGC CCGCA CCGCT CCGCG CCGCC CCCAA CCCAT CCCAG CCCAC CCCTA CCCTT CCCTG CCCTC CCCGA CCCGT CCCGG CCCGC CCCCA CCCCT CCCCG CCCCC
```

> 

```
     out9: 28.0KiB 0:00:00 [ 379MiB/s] [ 379MiB/s] [<=>                           ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 104% cpu 0.004 total
 | 4096 | 
    6  AAAAAA AAAAAT AAAAAG AAAAAC AAAATA AAAATT AAAATG AAAATC AAAAGA AAAAGT AAAAGG AAAAGC AAAACA AAAACT AAAACG AAAACC AAATAA AAATA...
                ...  CCCGCG CCCGCC CCCCAA CCCCAT CCCCAG CCCCAC CCCCTA CCCCTT CCCCTG CCCCTC CCCCGA CCCCGT CCCCGG CCCCGC CCCCCA CCCCCT CCCCCG CCCCCC


     out9:  128KiB 0:00:00 [ 482MiB/s] [ 482MiB/s] [<=>                           ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 39% cpu 0.012 total
 | 16384 | 
    7  AAAAAAA AAAAAAT AAAAAAG AAAAAAC AAAAATA AAAAATT AAAAATG AAAAATC AAAAAGA AAAAAGT AAAAAGG AAAAAGC AAAAACA AAAAACT AAAAACG AAAA...
                ... CCCCAA CCCCCAT CCCCCAG CCCCCAC CCCCCTA CCCCCTT CCCCCTG CCCCCTC CCCCCGA CCCCCGT CCCCCGG CCCCCGC CCCCCCA CCCCCCT CCCCCCG CCCCCCC


     out9:  576KiB 0:00:00 [ 865MiB/s] [ 865MiB/s] [<=>                           ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 47% cpu 0.013 total
 | 65536 | 
    8  AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAT AAAAAAAG AAAAAAAC AAAAAATA AAAAAATT AAAAAATG AAAAAATC AAAAAAGA AAAAAAGT AAAAAAGG AAAAAAGC AAAAAACA AAAAAAC...
                ...  CCCCCCAG CCCCCCAC CCCCCCTA CCCCCCTT CCCCCCTG CCCCCCTC CCCCCCGA CCCCCCGT CCCCCCGG CCCCCCGC CCCCCCCA CCCCCCCT CCCCCCCG CCCCCCCC


     out9: 2.50MiB 0:00:00 [1.71GiB/s] [1.71GiB/s] [<=>                           ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.01s user 0.00s system 81% cpu 0.015 total
 | 262144 | 
    9  AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAT AAAAAAAAG AAAAAAAAC AAAAAAATA AAAAAAATT AAAAAAATG AAAAAAATC AAAAAAAGA AAAAAAAGT AAAAAAAGG AAAAAAAGC AAAA...
                ... CCCCAC CCCCCCCTA CCCCCCCTT CCCCCCCTG CCCCCCCTC CCCCCCCGA CCCCCCCGT CCCCCCCGG CCCCCCCGC CCCCCCCCA CCCCCCCCT CCCCCCCCG CCCCCCCCC


     out9: 11.0MiB 0:00:00 [ 328MiB/s] [ 328MiB/s] [<=>                           ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.03s user 0.01s system 91% cpu 0.046 total
 | 1048576 | 
    10  AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAT AAAAAAAAAG AAAAAAAAAC AAAAAAAATA AAAAAAAATT AAAAAAAATG AAAAAAAATC AAAAAAAAGA AAAAAAAAGT AAAAAAAAGG AA...
                ... CCCTA CCCCCCCCTT CCCCCCCCTG CCCCCCCCTC CCCCCCCCGA CCCCCCCCGT CCCCCCCCGG CCCCCCCCGC CCCCCCCCCA CCCCCCCCCT CCCCCCCCCG CCCCCCCCCC
```

> 

```
     out9: 48.0MiB 0:00:00 [ 262MiB/s] [ 262MiB/s] [<=>                           ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.16s user 0.02s system 91% cpu 0.195 total
 | 4194304 | 
    11  AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAT AAAAAAAAAAG AAAAAAAAAAC AAAAAAAAATA AAAAAAAAATT AAAAAAAAATG AAAAAAAAATC AAAAAAAAAGA AAAAAAAAAGT AAA...
                ... CCCCTT CCCCCCCCCTG CCCCCCCCCTC CCCCCCCCCGA CCCCCCCCCGT CCCCCCCCCGG CCCCCCCCCGC CCCCCCCCCCA CCCCCCCCCCT CCCCCCCCCCG CCCCCCCCCCC


     out9:  208MiB 0:00:00 [ 251MiB/s] [ 251MiB/s] [ <=>                          ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.70s user 0.07s system 92% cpu 0.839 total
 | 16777216 | 
    12  AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAT AAAAAAAAAAAG AAAAAAAAAAAC AAAAAAAAAATA AAAAAAAAAATT AAAAAAAAAATG AAAAAAAAAATC AAAAAAAAAAGA AAAAAA...
                ... CCCCCCCTG CCCCCCCCCCTC CCCCCCCCCCGA CCCCCCCCCCGT CCCCCCCCCCGG CCCCCCCCCCGC CCCCCCCCCCCA CCCCCCCCCCCT CCCCCCCCCCCG CCCCCCCCCCCC


     out9:  896MiB 0:00:03 [ 252MiB/s] [ 252MiB/s] [  <=>                         ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  2.97s user 0.33s system 92% cpu 3.566 total
 | 67108864 | 
    13  AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAT AAAAAAAAAAAAG AAAAAAAAAAAAC AAAAAAAAAAATA AAAAAAAAAAATT AAAAAAAAAAATG AAAAAAAAAAATC AAAAAAAAAAA...
                ...  CCCCCCCCCCCTC CCCCCCCCCCCGA CCCCCCCCCCCGT CCCCCCCCCCCGG CCCCCCCCCCCGC CCCCCCCCCCCCA CCCCCCCCCCCCT CCCCCCCCCCCCG CCCCCCCCCCCCC


     out9: 3.75GiB 0:00:15 [ 253MiB/s] [ 253MiB/s] [          <=>                 ]
( nice echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  12.65s user 1.40s system 92% cpu 15.188 total
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer that I got after several tries. Basically, from the same idea that I have, I replace the existing array with the new one that contains the elements of the concatenated string. For the index of temp: m * length(bases_2) + n + 1. I'm simulating a 2D array where the row index is m and the column index is n in single dimension. length(bases_2) represents the number of columns, multiply m by this value to get the starting position of the m-th row in the array. n represents the column index within the m-th row, add n to the starting position of the row to get the index of the cell at position (m, n) in the simulated 2D array. Add 1 because awk is 1-indexed.

```
awk -v k=3 '
BEGIN {
  split("A T G C", bases_1, " ")
  split("A T G C", bases_2, " ")
  while (i < k - 1) {
    i += 1
    delete temp
    for (m in bases_1) {
      for (n in bases_2) {
        temp[m * length(bases_2) + n + 1] = bases_1[m] bases_2[n]
      }
    }
    delete bases_2
    for (t in temp) {
      bases_2[t] = temp[t]
    }
  }
  for (b in bases_2) {
    print bases_2[b]
  }
}
'
```

Comment: Don't add a comment under your answer, say whatever you have to say in your answer.